# Redirect in iframe with ios browser freezes Phaser canvas

Tags: ios, iphone, iframe, freeze, phaser-framework

I use Phaser to create a game but I found an problem for using it in for example facebook. When an redirect is done within an iframe the canvas is not responding after a click.

Example:
I have a IFrame and within the iframe I redirect to the game.html. When I click in the game.html everything freezes.

Everything works fine when using a computer (any browser), windows phone or android, but with an iphone or ipad it won't work.

Below are the example files to replay the problem...

index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe src="click.html" height="900" width="800"/>
</body>
</html>
click.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>

      <a href="Game.html">CLICK HERE</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

Game.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
           <style>
            body{overflow:hidden;}
             #game_div {
                 width: 760px;
                 height: 1100px;
                 margin: auto;
             }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./Game/phaser.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./Game/main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

      <div id="game_div"> </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(760, 1100, Phaser.AUTO, 'game_div');
var overlay, countdownText;
var counter = 0;

var main_state = {
    preload: function() {       

    },
    create: function () {

        //game overlay
        overlay = game.add.graphics(0, 0);
        overlay.beginFill(0x00A54F, 0.8);
        overlay.drawRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);

        countdownText = game.add.text((game.width / 2), (game.height / 2), counter, { font: "65px Arial", fill: "#ffffff", align: "center" });
        countdownText.anchor.set(0.5,0.5);

    },
    update: function() {
        countdownText.setText(counter++);
    }
}

game.state.add('main', main_state);  
game.state.start('main');
```

TNX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, with thanks to Rich Davey.

When I add the following code it works:

```
game.stage.disableVisibilityChange = true;
```